# File Upload by js

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload

I am trying to upload a file to my site using javascript. But the file doesnt appear in the specified directory (upload/images). The directory has attributes 777. Console.log(f) shows in Chrome that file length is 9, so it should be written. What s wrong?
Heres my code:

html:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="14%"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="84%"><input name="topic" type="text" id="topic" size="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>Detail</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="3" id="detail"></textarea></td>
<img id="pastedImage"></img>
</tr>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('detail').onpaste = function (event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
    this.Files = event.file;
};
let filepath = "upload/images/tmp.png";
//reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
let f = new File([this.Files], filepath);
console.log(f);

//let photo = document.getElementById("image-file").files[0];  // file from input
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append("photo", f);                                
req.open("POST", '/upload/images');
req.send(formData);
```

Comment: HTTP uploads only write to files to the disk if your web server is explicitly writing them. Otherwise a POST request is handled just like a GET request on the server, and if you have no handler for POST requests, they will either be rejected or ignored. What type of HTTP server are you running? (NodeJS, IIS, Apache, etc)

Comment: i think the server is Apache